# how to remove more 1 decimal numbers on a number

Tags: php

What's the simple way to remove more than 1 decimal number from source number .
***for example source numbers are :***

> 1st source number is : 56.48216585224
>   2nd source number is: 93

***Output must be  :***

> 1st output :  56.4
>   2nd output: 93

numbers are not static

**what's the simple way ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you **don't** want rounding, then:

```
$number = 56.48216585224;
echo substr($number, 0, strpos($number, '.')+2); // output: 56.4
```

Otherwise:

Use php round() or number_format()

http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Examples:

```
$number = 56.48216585224;
echo number_format($number, 1, '.', ''); // Output: 56.5
echo round($number, 1); // Output: 56.5
```

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest this PHP code for your requirement:

```
$n = 56.48216585224;
$m = floor($n * 10) / 10; // $m = 56.4 now
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

```
print(quickFormat("56.48216585224"));
print(quickFormat("93"));


function quickFormat($number) {
    $number = explode(".", $number);
    if (isset($number[1])) {
        return $number[0] . "." . $number[1]{0};
    } else {
        return $number[0] ;
    }
}
```

Output

```
56.4
93
```